# foreach loop returns only first record after Linq query with multiple records

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, foreach

I have a Linq2SQL query running against a database provided by a third party. The main part of the query looks like this:

```
         var valuationQuery =
            from v in context.Valuations
            where v.ModelId == QualifiedModelId.ModelId
                && v.QualifyModelId == QualifiedModelId.Qualifier
                && v.LanguageCode == QualifiedModelId.LanguageCode
                && v.Edition == Data.Meta.Edition.CurrentEdition.Date
                && v.RegDate == yearReg.RegistrationDate
                && v.ValTypeDescription == "Normal"
                && v.MileageBandID == MileageBand
```

When I loop around it with a foreach loop, it works or fails depending on the select at the end. When the select specifies all the fields like this...

```
            select new
            {
                v.Value1,
                v.Value2,
                v.Value3,
                ... snip ...
                v.Value14,
                v.Value15,
                v.ValueTypeID
            };
```

... it works normally. When I do the following, the loop iterates the correct amount of times, but brings back the first record every time:

```
            select v;
```

I want to be able to select all the fields without specifying the names in case the vendor adds more fields (they really are called "Value1" upto "Value15"), which means I can change one constant in my code and update the DBML and all the relevant code will lookup from the correct amount of fields. This query (and similar ones) are used in various places, so I'm looking for the least-effort in the future!

I have run SQL Profiler to ensure the query being run returns the correct results, and it does.

The foreach loop is this (the Convert's are due to the very badly designed database having very inconsistent datatypes):

```
  foreach (var record in valuationQuery)
      {
            int CurrentValType = Convert.ToInt32(record.ValueTypeID);
            string FieldName = "Value";

            if (MPLower.MileagePointID >= 1 && MPLower.MileagePointID <= MaxMileagePoints)
            {
                FieldName = "Value" + MPLower.MileagePointID.ToString().Trim();
                MPLower.MileagePointPounds[CurrentValType] = Convert.ToInt32(record.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName).GetValue(record, null));
            }

            if (MPHigher.MileagePointID >= 1 && MPHigher.MileagePointID <= MaxMileagePoints)
            {
                FieldName = "Value" + MPHigher.MileagePointID.ToString().Trim();
                MPHigher.MileagePointPounds[CurrentValType] = Convert.ToInt32(record.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName).GetValue(record, null));
            }
        }
```

I'm new to C# (I've inherited some code), so I realise it's probably something stupid I've done or not done!! Please can anyone help?

Comment: Please show a bit more code. This should work.

Comment: Can you show us what you're doing in the foreach loop?

Comment: can you show please yuor foreah loop ?

Comment: Without the code for the `foreach` loop (i.e. the condition that's failing), how in the world would we be able to help solve this?

Comment: I'm very confused... so when you select the object it doesn't work but if you select all the fields it does? That **can't** happen. **Can't.** More code needed.

Comment: This feels a little reminiscent of an issue with closures, where you close over a variable in a loop but the variables get updated so at the end of the loop you only have the final value.  I'd have to see what you're doing in your foreach though to know for sure.

Comment: Hi guys, more code added above for clarity! It's run immediately after the query, and I've tried removing everything after the int CurrentValType line in case the reflection code was causing problems

Comment: How have you determined that it's same record every time?  Are you inspecting it in the debugger?

Comment: I'm still running it in the IDE, (not in production yet), and stepping through it. I've also manually run the query that the profiler shows Linq has created to make sure the query on the SQL server brings the right results (which it does for both versions).

Comment: Do you have your primary keys set up properly in your L2S datacontext? This kinda sounds like an identity map issue.

Comment: Just curious, if you select both the object and its values, like `select {v, v.Value1, v.Value2...}` then is there a mismatch between v and the values?

Comment: The data context showed primary keys but the database (don't shoot me, remember it's a third party database!) has none on that table. I removed the keys out of the DBML, and now it's working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Identity Maps**

A common problem when using ORMs (ok, maybe not exactly common, but it can happen) is that a query which you expect to return distinct records ends up returning multiple copies of the same record. This is often caused by the ORM's Identity Map. Here's a quick overview of how it normally works.

The identity map is essentially an object cache, based on the primary key of each object.

When you ask the ORM for a record with a certain primary key, it'll check to see if the record already exists in the identity map. If it does already exist, it'll return the existing record.

This is usually pretty handy, but sometimes things go wrong. If two objects have the same primary key, or if you haven't specified what the primary keys are (forcing the ORM to guess), the identity map can't distinguish between them, and the first one will always be returned.

The moral of the story is, always double-check your primary keys if you are seeing multiple copies of the same record where you shouldn't be!

---

In this question, the code

```
    select new
    {
        v.Value1,
        v.Value2,
        v.Value3,
        ... snip ...
        v.Value14,
        v.Value15,
        v.ValueTypeID
    };
```

works because you are using the select new{} projection to return an anonymous type, which bypasses the identity map.

```
    select v
```

selects the objects directly, which does use the identity map, causing the problem you were seeing.